# Unable to import multiple images into post table manually

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made a script that automatically imports data from CSV into wordpress posts tables. The post also has a featured image and multiple gallary images, however I'm unable to import them. Not sure how it saved the images path.

Currently it saves the images in below  manner, if I change anything in the image URL it won't show the image at all eventhough image exists in that path -

```
a:3:{
    i:0;
    s:117:"http://b42rent.com/underconstruction2/wp-content/uploads/job-manager-uploads/gallery_images/2017/06/Chrysanthemum.jpg";
    i:1;
    s:114:"http://b42rent.com/underconstruction2/wp-content/uploads/job-manager-uploads/gallery_images/2017/06/Hydrangeas.jpg";
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I should do it?

Comment: check this helps if u are importing WC Products  https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/